# PageIndex is not being set, when paginator is defined as static: true. Not able to maintain pagination state

Tags: angular, angular-material-table, paginator

Here is I am getting pageIndex and pageSize as input. Initialing datasource paginatore and setting data to dataSource.

```
  @Input()
  public set pageIndex(index: number) {
    this._pageIndex = index;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.paginator._changePageSize(this.paginator.pageSize);
    });
  }

  @Input()
  public set pageSize(pageSize: number) {
    this._pageSize = pageSize;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.paginator._changePageSize(this.paginator.pageSize);
    });
  }

  public get pageIndex(): number {
    return this._pageIndex;
  }

  public get pageSize(): number {
    return this._pageSize;
  }

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);

  @Input()
  public set data(d: any[]) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.data = d;
    this.selection.clear();
  }

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this._sort;
    this.filterCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((searchTerm: string) => {
        this.dataSource.filter = searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase();
      });
  }
```

I am defining mat-paginator like the following-

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

Here is my html template for paginator -

```
<mat-paginator #paginator (page)="pageChangeEvent($event)" [pageIndex]="pageIndex" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100, 500]" [pageSize]="pageSize" showFirstLastButtons>
        </mat-paginator>
```

How to reproduce the problem?

1. move to the next page suppose third page (i.e; pageIndex = 2)
2. reloading the page or move to another route and come back to the same route.

What behavior I want?
On navigating back to the same route or after reloading the page, I should be on the same pageIndex.

What is the problem?
But I am redirected to the first page i.e; pageInde = 0;

What is the behavior?
on reloading the page or routing back to the same route, for a moment I get pageIndex as 2, but after that it automatically get sets to 0.

Comment: Please someone answer this Question. I have been struggling in it for long. Thanks in Advance.